# "Attempted to read or write protected memory" error when changing SQL query in View Table in Visual Studio

Tags: sql, visual-studio, named-query

I really don't get it, why Visual Studio 2008 shows me such error:

```
Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt. (Microsoft Visual Studio)

------------------------------
Program Location:

   at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IntDestroyWindow(HandleRef hWnd)
   at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DestroyWindow(HandleRef hWnd)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DestroyHandle()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.DestroyHandle()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.ShowDialog(IWin32Window owner)
   at Microsoft.DataWarehouse.DataWarehouseUtilities.ShowDialog(Form form, IServiceProvider serviceProvider, IWin32Window owner)
   at Microsoft.DataWarehouse.DataWarehouseUtilities.ShowDialog(Form form, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
   at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Controls.NamedQueryBuilderDialog.ShowDialog(DataSourceView dsv, DataTable dataTable)
   at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Design.DataSourceDesigner.EditNamedQuery(Boolean replaceTable)
```

What I'm doing and where?
I have `View Table` in `Data Source Views` in certain cube in Visual Studio.
I want to edit `Named Query` of this view - change appearance of SQL code, because VS formatted SQL code in bad way (as for me).
I have 10 lines of code (with a few `select` subqueries) and I want change last line from this:

```
...
(SELECT id, desc, time FROM tab1) AS AM ON DZ.id = AM.id) AS POM) AS SUB ON SUB.id = tab.id
```

to this:

```
...
    ...
        ...
        (SELECT id, desc, time FROM tab1) AS AM ON DZ.id = AM.id
    ) AS POM
) AS SUB ON SUB.id = tab.id
```

And when I want to save changes (by clicking OK button) I get the above error. o.O

What's wrong? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think it's a bug of vs 2008, not necessarily related to your change.  Copy the changes and restart vs, try again.

Comment: It didn't help. I've also done `Window`-> `Reset Window Layout` and the error still is.

Comment: Then sorry I have no further idea. My old Delphi IDE used to run into a fetal error when I typed certain code. I always restart the IDE to solve the issue. Sometime, changing your code also helps.  Your sub query looks a little bit out of control. Do you have to do that?

Comment: No, of course I don't have to do that. ;) I was just a little bit surprised, that something like this happens. And I know that this code looks like a little bit out of control, but it's just short version of whole code.